# Load ViewController as child view in main view from other child view

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I´m coding an application using swift3/xcode 8. My application have a central view controller, called MenuViewController, which is responsible for the side menu.
Inside this one, i load the other views as child views, so in this way I can use the side menu in all other views.

But I´m in doubt now: In a specific view controller I have a table view, which have a method to perform an action on selecting an item. This action calls other 
view and pass a parameter.

So, how do I load this view in the BaseViewController with this parameter? Is it possible?

Please let me know if it is not clear....

Thank you!

**Update 1:**

I´m using a solution I found interesting: 
[Cocoacasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq-lHR5ZOW0)

Basically I have this code on MenuViewController:

*Declare the view to be loaded in MenuViewController:*

```
    lazy var filamentoViewController: FilamentoViewController = {

        let storyboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilamentoViewController") as! FilamentoViewController 
        self.addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: viewController)
        return viewController
    }()
```

*Adds the viewcontroller as child in MenuViewController:*

```
    private fun addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController)
    {
      addChildViewController(childViewController)
      view.addSubView(childViewController.view)
      childViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
      childViewController.view.autoResizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

*Code in FilamentoViewController which calls other viewcontroller:*

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
      let editFilamentoViewController:EditFilamentoViewController = EditFilamentoViewController()
      editFilamentoViewController.cod = indexPath.row
      self.presentViewController(editFilamentoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

*The code*

```
      self.presentViewController(editFilamentoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*is the one I want do load into MenuViewController.*

**Update 2:**

MenuViewController is a CentreViewController. I load the other views in the center and the menu comes from left.

Comment: Q.1 - Is MenuViewController is LeftViewController or CentreViewController?
Q.2 - How are you adding Left - Centre ViewController's?
Q.3 - Please provide some code.

Comment: I´ve just added an update! thks

Comment: What is the actual question? and what is `BaseViewController`?

Comment: Zaid, the question is how do I call the method _self.presentViewController_, which is inside a child view in the menu view...i it clear? Tks

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.presentViewController` from your child view controller?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in controller for your kind of requirement(i.e UISplitViewController) , Have you considered this?

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller)

[Sample Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

And there are also slide-out menu libraries.

[slide out menu](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift)

Comment: Thank you RavikanthM ! I will check...Iám starting coding now, learning by myself...a little bit dificult...to be honest with you i dont know this component.